# BackgroundWorker and Timer issues - UI Freeze

Tags: c#, timer, backgroundworker

Originally my code had a `Timer` that would continuously ping the server to see if it's connected. However, I also had a `Timer` in order to display the current time. This is what it looked like originally:

```
public Main()
{
    /* let's check if there is a connection to the database */
    isDbAvail = new Timer();
    isDbAvail.Interval = 8000;
    isDbAvail.Tick += new EventHandler(isOnline);
    isDbAvail.Start();

    /* the clock */
    clock = new Timer();
    clock.Interval = 1000;
    clock.Tick += new EventHandler(clockTimer_Tick);
    clock.Start();
}

private void isOnline(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Connection connection = new Connection();
    changeStatus(connection.isDbAvail());
}

private void clockTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Up until now, everything worked fine except for the fact that when it came to check the database, the entire UI would freeze and would lag about 3 seconds. I did some research and found BackgroundWorker and changed everything to the following:

```
public Main()
{
    isDbAvail = new BackgroundWorker();
    isDbAvail.DoWork += isOnline;

        /* the clock */
    clock = new Timer();
    clock.Interval = 1000;
    clock.Tick += new EventHandler(clockTimer_Tick);
    clock.Start();
}

private void isOnline(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(8000);
        Connection connection = new Connection();
        changeStatus(connection.isDbAvail());
    }
}
```

When I run this, nothing happens and I get no errors either. I'm pretty sure there is something very crucial missing here that I cannot seem to grasp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
isDbAvail.RunWorkerAsync();
```

after

```
isDbAvail.DoWork
```

line

Comment: LOL, well that was easy.